# How can I configure NHibernate so that I can create a new (Brand New) session as I need it?

Tags: c#, session, nhibernate

I have a console application that imports a file that the customer gives us.

This file has multiple records and they need to be imported.

If I use the single session to import them all, if one of them fails, they all fail.  This is terrible.

I have been going crazy trying to simply figure out how to create a session.  Every single resource I have read is about how to configure NHibernate with Structure map in an MVC project to have a session per request.

I get it.  That is good for the web. I know.

I cannot have that here. I need a new session for every record.

I want this

```
foreach(var record in recordsToImport)
{
     //CREATE NEW SESSION or RANSACTION //I don't care about wrapping it in UnitOfWork
     //BEGIN TRANSACTION HERE
     myRepoClass.Update(record);
     //COMMIT TRANSACTION HERE

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably just want a new transaction in the loop.

For a new transaction, your code should look like

```
ISession session = ...; 
// Create the session as you are currently doing it
// Pass the session into myRepoClass

foreach(var record in recordsToImport)
{
     using (ITransaction trx = session.BeginTransaction())
     {
         myRepoClass.Update(record);
         trx.Commit();
     }
}
```

Comment: The transaction commit implies a Flush, so that call is not needed. Perhaps you meant Clear() to remove all active objects from the session? Also, I would strongly recommend a using-statement to manage the transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @OskarBerggren . I had forgotten that Commit does a Flush.  I've edited it to reflect your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

See the [NHibernate documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#configuration-hibernatejdbc):

> ... opening an `ISession` is as simple as:
>
> ```
> ISession session = sessions.OpenSession();
> ```

... where `sessions` is an `ISessionFactory`.